# Avoiding edit spam for link edit

Tags: discussion, editing

I noticed an external linked resource had moved and have done a quick search and replace for questions and answers that link the old resource, to prevent broken links.

That has pulled some old Q&A to the top of activity page. I'm not sure if that is annoying to other site users.

Is there a way to make these sorts of edits without that effect, but still allowing for my efforts to be monitored lest I make the wrong change?

Related: Is it better to schedule this work in small batches (say 2-3 edits per day), to limit noise but extend the work, or is it better to do everything in one go, changing the first page of recent activity but only once per expired link.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is a way, but I wouldn't worry about it. Resurfacing older content once in a while isn't a big deal.